# Show that for an invertible operator $A$ on a Banach space, the spectrum is contained in the annulus $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\leq |z|\leq \|A\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that for an invertable operator $A$, the spectrum is contained in the annulus $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\leq |z|\leq \|A\|$

I came up with a proof: first we show that if $|z|>\|A\|$ then $zI-A$ Is invertible. That follows from the von Neumann's lemma $I-A/z$ since $\|A\|/z<1$. Thus we prove the upper bound. The lower bound comes from similar reasoning but for $A^{-1}$, we note that the spectrum of $A$ is just reciprocals (and $0$) of the spectrum of $A^{-1}$. Thus by our previous proof the spectrum of $A^{-1}$ is contained in $|z|<\|A^{-1}\|$ and thus  $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\leq \frac{1}{|z|}$ as desired.

Is this correct? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but you made some mistakes in writing at the end. If $z$ is in the spectrum of $A$ then $z \neq 0$ and $\frac 1  z$ is in the spectrum of $A^{-1}$ so $|\frac  1  z| \leq \|A^{-1}\|$ and we get the inequality $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1} \leq |z|$ by taking reciprocals.